# How to create an inequality loop (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to code a loop so that the program checks the sum and if the sum < random then it starts again, but this isn't working as I get errors. Here is the code:

```
int o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9;
boolean thugloop = false;
 System.out.println("Woah, you beat the thug; but now the thug is angry and he won't rest until he beats you.");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                thugloop = true;
                  System.out.println("Pick your numbers again");
                while(thugloop = true){

                    o4=reader.nextInt();
                o5=reader.nextInt();
                o6=reader.nextInt();
                o7=reader.nextInt();
                o8=reader.nextInt();
                int sumhop2 = o4+o5+o6+o7+o8;
                  int angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85); 

                  if(sumhop2>angrythug){
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                      System.out.println("Woah, you are really good at this!");
                       System.out.println("But the thug is getting angrier.");
                         o4=reader.nextInt();
                o5=reader.nextInt();
                o6=reader.nextInt();
                o7=reader.nextInt();
                o8=reader.nextInt();

      **sumhop2 = o5 + o5 + o7 + o8;
     int angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);** 


                    }else if(sumhop2<angrythug){

                      //other code goes here.


                    }

                }
```

Disregarding the static void.. etc... what is wrong with the code?

The code around the ** ** is the main issue, this park doesn't work; how can  I fix this?

Comment: You would get a huge clue by reading the error message. If you don't understand it, post it. And please, indent your code properly. Your IDE does that with a single keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems :

Assignment instead of comparison :

```
while(thugloop = true)
```

Should be :

```
while(thugloop == true) // or while(thugloop)
```

Re-declaring a variable with the same name :

```
int angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);
```

should be

```
angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);
```

Beside that, you should reset `thugloop` to false somewhere in order for the loop to terminate.

Comment: Thank you very much; what is the difference here in '=' and '=='?

Comment: @Aakarsh `= true` assigns true to the variable while `== true` tests if the current value of the variable is true.

Comment: Thankyou, I got this to work, but the loop itself doesn't work after a while. The first time, I entered 5 17's, works. The second time it stops, just no response from the console? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first of all when you are doing

```
while(thugloop = true)
```

you are actually assigning true to thughloop which is equal to while(true) in java either define

```
thugloop = true;
while(thugloop)
```

like this or in your code make it thughloop == true

also to avoid inifinite loop accept a value like -1 which would exit/break the loop.

`int angrythug` before if and inside if are in same scope of method you cannot do that read : http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html reuse the angrythug variable inside the if block