# Java loop stops working after second try

Tags: java

I am trying to make a console game (like Oregon trails) and I had a problem [with the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195589/how-to-create-an-inequality-loop-java/) but was solved later.

**this is just part of the code of the whole game.

Now the problem is, the loop doesn't work after the second try; here is the code:

```
 int o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9;
boolean thugloop = false;
 System.out.println("Woah, you beat the thug; but now the thug is angry and he won't rest until he beats you.");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                thugloop = true;
                  System.out.println("Pick your numbers again");
                while(thugloop = true){

                    o4=reader.nextInt();
                o5=reader.nextInt();
                o6=reader.nextInt();
                o7=reader.nextInt();
                o8=reader.nextInt();
                int sumhop2 = o4+o5+o6+o7+o8;
                  int angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85); 

                  if(sumhop2>angrythug){
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                      System.out.println("Woah, you are really good at this!");
                       System.out.println("But the thug is getting angrier. Put in 5 more numbers:");
                         o4=reader.nextInt();
                o5=reader.nextInt();
                o6=reader.nextInt();
                o7=reader.nextInt();
                o8=reader.nextInt();

      **sumhop2 = o5 + o5 + o7 + o8;
     angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);** 


                    }else if(sumhop2<angrythug){

                      //other code goes here.
           break;

                    }

                }
```

So it works the first time, but when it says "the thug is getting angrier. Put in 5 more.." and I put in 5 more numbers, nothing happens, it's just a blinking cursor there.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code properly. I get a headache from trying to figure out where blocks end here.

Comment: `while(thugloop = true)` should be `while(thugloop)` (or, less recommended, `while(thugloop == true)`)

Comment: @Keppil, I am a noob here, I cannot format properly; sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enter 5 more numbers, you reach the start of the loop, which requires 5 more numbers to be input. Hence the blinking cursor.

Perhaps the first 5 inputs should be requested before the loop begins :

```
            o4=reader.nextInt();
            o5=reader.nextInt();
            o6=reader.nextInt();
            o7=reader.nextInt();
            o8=reader.nextInt();
            int sumhop2 = o4+o5+o6+o7+o8;
            int angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85); 
            while(thugloop == true) {
                if(sumhop2>angrythug){
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                     System.out.println("Woah, you are really good at this!");
                     System.out.println("But the thug is getting angrier. Put in 5 more numbers:");
                     o4=reader.nextInt();
                     o5=reader.nextInt();
                     o6=reader.nextInt();
                     o7=reader.nextInt();
                     o8=reader.nextInt();

                     sumhop2 = o5 + o5 + o7 + o8;
                     angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);
                     ...
```

Comment: @Aakarsh Because outside the loop you get the input for the first iteration. Then, if another iteration is required, you get more input (in the if statement). You could also keep it inside the while loop and instead remove the `nextInt` lines from the if statement. The important point is that in each iteration of the while loop you only read 5 integers from the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers are great.I am making this game, I am almost done, but I ran into another problem. I just posted it. Its a weird problem

Answer (score 0):

after `the thug is getting angrier. Put in 5 more..` you are accepting 5 values doing the calculation in angrythug then the if block exits you are back to while loop. So print your result after the 5 intake values in if block.

edit: or do :

```
while(sumhop2 > angrythug){
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Woah, you are really good at this!");
System.out.println("But the thug is getting angrier. Put in 5 more numbers:");
            o4=reader.nextInt();
            o5=reader.nextInt();
            o6=reader.nextInt();
            o7=reader.nextInt();
            o8=reader.nextInt();

  **sumhop2 = o5 + o5 + o7 + o8;
 angrythug= 3 + (int)(Math.random()*85);** 
}
// for sumhop2 < angrythug code goes here
```

// above loop will exit when the angrythug is greater than sumhop2